# Simplify regular expression

Tags: regex, computer-science

I want to simplify this regular expression:

```
0*|0*1(ε|0*1)*00*
```

I used this identity:

```
(R+S)*=(R*S*)*=(R*+S*)*
```

and couldn't get better than this:

`0*|0*1(0*1)*00*` `[(ε|0*1)*=(ε*0*1)*=(0*1)*]`

Can this regular expression be simplified even more, and how? I have no clue what else to do. :)

**EDIT 1**: I altered `+` to `|` ,for `+` could stand for "one or more times", beside alternation which is now denoted by `|`.
Explanation of notation:

```
1) ε stands for empty word
2) * is Kleene star
3) AB is just a concatenation of languages of regular expressions A and B.
```

**EDIT 2**: Formal proof that this reduces to (0*1)*0+|ε:

```
  0*|0*1(ε|0*1)*00* = 
= 0*|0*1(0*1)*0+ =
= 0*|(0*1)+0+ =
= 0+|ε|(0*1)+0+ =
= ε0+|(0*1)+0+|ε
= (ε|(0*1)+)0+|ε
= (0*1)*0+|ε
```

Is there any way to reduce it further to `(0|1)*0|ε`?

Comment: In computer-science regex, isn't there a quantifier which means `match one or more times` ?. In normal regex, you use `+`. Which means that `00*` would be the same as `0+`. Otherwise what are you trying to match ? As a last resort you may try [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Given that you're not using traditional regex for your expressions, can you point to a description of what you are using?

Comment: Ok, per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression, I'm assuming that `+` stands for "alternation".

Comment: Yes, + stood for alternation, but I edited the question and changed it to | and replaced 00* with 0+. I actually wanted to find a complement of regular expression `(0|1)*1`, so I derived a DFA from that expression, made all its final states non-final and vice versa, and then tried to derive the regular expression for that DFA. : ) Thanks for cs.stackexchange.com link, by the way. : )

Comment: So do you agree with my answer?

Comment: Also, the cs.stackexchange.com reference was from @Hamza :-)

Comment: Nice job getting it that far. Can you prove that you can eliminate the `+` as a next step?

Comment: I'm trying, but I have no idea what to do next. We should end the proof with `(0|1)*0|ε` as suggested in answers below, it's just I don't know how to get there. However, we're closer now than at the beginning. \o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to formally reduce given regular expression to ε|(0|1)*0. 
This is the proof:

```
 0*|0*1(ε|0*1)*00* = 
= 0*|0*1(0*1)*0+ =
= 0*|(0*1)+0+ =
= 0+|ε|(0*1)+0+ =
= ε0+|(0*1)+0+|ε =
= (ε|(0*1)+)0+|ε =
= (0*1)*0+|ε =
= (0*1)*0*0|ε = #
= (0|1)*0|ε
```

The trick was to use the identity `(A*B)*A*` = `(A|B)*` of which I wasn't aware when the question was asked, in the step marked with #.

Answer (score 4):

(Update: See edit history for long, sad story of previous incorrect attempts).

I (now) believe this reduces to:

```
ε|(0|1)*0
```

in other words, either:

- The empty string
- Any string of ones and zeros ending in 0

Proving this is another matter altogether. ;-)

Comment: Yes, E|(0+1)*0 should be correct because I needed the complement of (0|1)*1 which is every string ending in 1. However, I need a formal proof. I'm stuck with this: 0*|0*1(0*1)*00*. So, I could write this as 0*|(0*1)+0+, but how to derive E|(0+1)*0 from that? :) About Greek epsilon: I just copied the character from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon pasted it and it worked, although I wasn't 100% sure it would. :)

Comment: Can you confirm the identities I listed are accurate?

Comment: Yes, they are accurate.

Comment: Yes, this is basically it. It can be further reduced to `[01]*0|`

Comment: Right. I was trying to stay with the formal language style regex ... :-)

Comment: The proof seems nasty, though, which is what the OP is really looking for. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

I think it reduces to this `(0*1)*0+|`

Comment: After further reflection, the `+` is unnecessary, isn't it?

Comment: How did you get this? :)

Comment: I would think its necessary, otherwise `00` wouldn't match. On the other hand, `(0*1)*0*` would be the same as `(0*1)*0+|`

Comment: @sin Yep, you're right. I can't believe what a brain teaser this is. What do you think of my latest (version) of my answer?